# JS remember toggle class state on page reload

Tags: javascript

I have a div that expands and collapse on a button click that works just fine. I am now trying to see if it is possible to add a cookie to the JS that the div remembers the last state on a page reload.

The script I am using is:

The html:

```
<div id="myDIV" class="modal-body vcenter noti_open">
```

and the JS:

```
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
$(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up");
});

function myFunction() {

var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
element.classList.toggle("noti_close");
}
</script>
```

How to add a cookie to the browser to remember the change in state of #myDIV?

Comment: Don't use cookies. Use `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use localStorage instead of cookies.
If something blocking you from using local storage, the following shlould work.

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up");
   setCookie('toggle-satus', !toBoolean(getCookie('toggle-satus')), 7);
});

function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.toggle("noti_close");
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ now.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function toBoolean(str) {
   return (str === "true");
}


$(this).load(function(){
  var toggleStatus = toBoolean(getCookie('toggle-satus'));
  if(toggleStatus){
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.addClass("noti_close");
  }
})
```

Comment: @Ivar Missed that. Thanks for noticing it. Edited the original answer

Comment: thanks for asnwering. The code does not seems to work for me. There is some layout style missing, but I've made a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/intered/rh4ea0yq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `localstorage`:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up");
   localStorage.setItem('toggle-satus', ! (localStorage.getItem('toggle-satus') == "true") );
});

function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.toggle("noti_close");
}

$(this).load(function(){
  var toggleStatus = (localStorage.getItem('toggle-satus') == "true");
  if(toggleStatus){
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.addClass("noti_close");
  }
})
```

Comment: @Ivar Sorry my bad, Thanks for noting, I fixed it!

Comment: Hi Abd, thanks for answering. The code does not seem to work for me. There is some layout style missing, but I've made a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/intered/rh4ea0yq/2/